# How to solve this equation that contains very similar denominators?

Tags: polynomials

How to solve this equation for $x$ in reals, without using theory of complex number?
$$\frac{a}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}+\frac{b}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}=1$$
Where $a$ and $b$ is some constants

Please write down a step-by-step solution with a good explanation to this equation. I spent a lot of time trying to solve it but could not find an answer.

According to [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iwke0frbow), it has four roots:

[image]

<sub>I don't know which title and tags I should use for this question, please edit.</sub>

Comment: In your graph, you put $y$ instead of $x$. Is that what you want? Or is it this graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tovdun7cym

Comment: Have you tried to cross multiply and simplify?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan Yes, the mistake has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach yielding solutions by reducing the issue **to solve successive  quadratic equations** :

Let us write the expression under the form :

$$\frac{a}{X^{2}}+\frac{b}{X^{2}-4}=1\tag{1}$$

where we have set :

$$X=x+\frac{1}{x}\tag{2}$$

Let us rewrite (1) under the form :

$$\dfrac{a(X^2-4)+bX^2}{X^2(X^2-4)}=1\tag{3}$$

Setting

$$Y=X^2\tag{4}$$

(3) amounts to

$$aY-4a+bY=Y(Y-4) \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ Y^2-(4+a+b)Y+4a=0\tag{5}$$

It remains to solve (5), then, in a backward way  (4), then (2) to obtain the different values of $x$, some of them happening to be complex.

**Example** : Let us take $a=1, b=3$, which gives $Y=4\pm2\sqrt{3}$, i.e.,

$$Y_1=5.73205  \ \ \text{and} \ \  Y_2=2.26795$$

from which

$$X_1=\pm \sqrt{Y_1}=\pm 2.39417 \ \ \text{and} \ \ X_2=\pm \sqrt{Y_2}=\pm 1.50597 \tag{6}$$

It remains to solve the four quadratic equations

$$x+\dfrac{1}{x}=X$$

for the different values of $X$ in (6) : the first ones (with $X_1$) will give 4 real roots :

$$x =  1.85512, \ \ 0.53905, \ \ -0.53905, \ \ -1.85512$$

the two others  (with $X_2$) will give 4 complex roots.

**Remark** : the initial equation (and the equivalent polynomial equation) is such that if $x$ is a solution, then $1/x$ is also a solution : it is said that such a polynomial is ["**reciprocal**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) (some say "palindromic"), characterised equivalently by the fact that $a_{k}=a_{n-k}$ for all $k$, if $n$ denotes the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by doing this:
$$
\frac{a}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}+\frac{b}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}=
\frac{ax^2}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2  x^2}+\frac{bx^2}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2  x^2}=
\frac{ax^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{bx^2}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}=1
$$
Now multiply both sides by $(x^2 + 1)^2 (x^2 -1 )^2$:
$$
ax^2 (x^2 -1)^2 + bx^2 (x^2 +1)^2 = (x^2 + 1)(x^2 -1 )(x^2 + 1)(x^2 -1 ) = (x^4 -1 )^2
$$
now set $t= x^2$ and open the parentheses on the left-hand side: 
$$
at^3 - 2at^2 +at+bt^3 + 2bt^2 +bt = t^4 - 2t^2+1
$$
which is a quartic equation.

Comment: I have provided a solution which is rather classical with so-called "reciprocal polynomials".